# Как составить запрос к mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, дорогие профессионалы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вот такой запрос:

У нас есть поле ввода. В него человек через запятую пишет ключевые слова:
Море, пальма, девушки, C++, яма, google. Количество слов произвольное. Порядок тоже.

Имеем в mysql таблицу. В которой среди прочих полей есть поле "ключевые слова".
Приведем несколько строк в пример:

*id1: Пальма, яма, Алексей, котики, погода.

id2: С++, яма, море.

id3: Пальма, масло, девушки, яндекс, другое, яд.

id4: Котики, google, яма, С++, девушки, море, пальма.

id5: Кит, лужа, жаба, картина, дрон.

id6: Кролик, бегун, яма, карта, картошка.*

Необходимо составить запрос к таблице на выборку строк в которых есть слова, которые ввел пользователь, при этом так, чтобы строки расположились в порядке "чем больше совпадений тем выше строка". Тоесть строка id4 должна быть первой. За ней следует id2, id1, id3, id6, id 5.

Как составить такой запрос пока у меня самого идей нет.

Есть только предположение, взять строку запроса, разбить на части по каждому ключу извлечь строки, затем сравнивая строки установить порядок. Но это получается очень громоздка и не красиво.

Если у кого-то есть идеи, как решить этот вопрос, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Используйте sphinx для ваших целей. На mysql нужна таблица в myasm текстовый индекс запрос через лайк не лайк и т.д. сфинкс справиться намного быстрее и точнее.

Comment: При такой структуре базы сделать это на SQL приемлимым по сложности запроса способом не выйдет. Можете попробовать встроенный в mysql "полнотекстовый поиск" (в гугле так и ввести). Либо, если нам действительно надо проверять на точное соответствие конкретных слов, считая "яма" и "ямы" абсолютно разными словами, то для начала надо вместо поля "ключевые слова" делать отдельную таблицу в которой для каждой ID отдельными записями будет лежать каждое слово (или даже id слов из  справочника слов)

Comment: Немного дополню @Mike. Можно изначально индексировать все данные в _несколько_ отдельных таблиц, где таблица1 -- "Слова в И.П.Е.Ч.", а таблица2 -- соответствие вхождений слов в ваши данные. Тогда вы можете разбивать ваш запрос на подстроки в ИПЕЧ, и это будет работать быстро.

Comment: @Andrewus чтоб я еще знал, как это делать =) Можете дать, где почитать об этом?

Comment: @anj1817, ключевые слова для поиска "Релевантность", "Ранжирование" и "Полнотекстовый поиск". Вот, например: https://habrahabr.ru/post/244561/

Comment: @Andrewus ух ты! Вот это интересно. Спасибо, пойду изучать.